# Is the sentence "I’ll remind you when that happened" correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms, sentence-meaning

I’m not a native speaker, so I’m utterly confused: in my language, which is Spanish, we’d say *“Te recordaré cuando eso pasó”*, but the one I’m asking about just sounds weird to me...

The context is basically a situation where one wants to bring back to another’s memory an event that, obviously, occurred in the past.

If it is not, feel free to provide the correct one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the proper context "I'll remind you when that happened" would be valid syntax/semantics and reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: Adding an _of_ or _about_ after _you_ would make it more clear that it's an embedded question complement clause and not a temporal adverb clause.

Comment: @HotLicks Then, would it be fine if i say “seems like I have to remind you when you almost died”?

Comment: @HotLicks "I'll remind you when that happened" means that I'll bring to your memory the time that the event occurred; "I'll remind you _of_ when that happend" means that I'll bring to your memory the _fact that the event occurred_, no?

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for answering!

Comment: @Conrado What you imply really makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexaVertes - If you were "muscle" for Al Capone.